# CDF and Inverse CDF calculating

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, uniform-distribution, inverse-function, monte-carlo

I am working on Monte-Carlo simulation. I decided to compare calculating of different functions with inverse CDF.

For example we have standard Gumbel distribution. Its cumulative distribution function is $F(x)=e^{−e^{−x}}$. So if we will compute such integral on the domain [0,1] we will receive the answer =  0.5400317077249.

For inverse transformation we need to recall natural logarithm function as an inverse of exponential function, so it is instantly obvious that quantile function for Gumbel distribution is $F^{−1}(p)=−\ln(−\ln(p))$, but if we will compute the final function $F(x)=e^{−e^{−(−\ln(−\ln(p)))}}$ on the same domain, uniformly distributed as $[0,1]$ the result will be 0.4999995231642060389 always.

Can somebody please help me to understand where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how you're really integrating $F(x) = x$ when you plug the inverse function into the original. That's not what we want. The relation between the integrals of $F(x)$ and $F^{-1}(p)$ is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions#Statement_of_the_theorem):

$$ \int\limits_a^bF(x)\,dx = bd - ac - \int\limits_c^dF^{-1}(p) \, dp $$

In our case, $F(x)$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[e^{-1}, e^{-e^{-1}}]$. So,

$$ \int\limits_0^1F(x)\,dx = e^{-e^{-1}} - \int\limits_{e^{-1}}^{e^{-e^{-1}}} F^{-1}(p) \, dp \approx 0.540032$$

as desired.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow you. The left hand side of your last equation, where $F(x)=e^{−e^{−x}}$, calculated by MC on the domain [0,1] equal to 0.540031860. The right-hand side is equal to 7.389056099 - inverted integral,  on the domain [−2.718281828, 7.389056099] - can you please explain, how did you obtain these bounds?

Comment: I think my notation is confusing you. The correct bounds are approximately $[0.367879, 0.692201]$. I obtained these bounds by the relation, $p_1 = e^{-e^{0}} \approx 0.367879$ and $p_2 = e^{-e^{-1}} \approx 0.692201$.

Comment: Look at the graphs of $F(x)$ and $F^{-1}(p)$. They are inverses of each other. So the range of $F(x)$ must be the domain of $F^{-1}(p)$. The range of $F(x)$ is $[0.367879,0.692201]$.

Comment: Yes,  I got in now.  Your formula seems to be absolutely right. Thank you very much! Can you please give me a hint, where i can a read theoretical staff, because my calculations were very bad.